# Windows 7 на Kaby Lake

Tags: windows-7, windows-10, cpu

У меня вполне мощный ноут с процем i5 7 поколения, который не поддерживает 7 винда, но это касательно обновлений. Везде пишется, что можно ставить, но нигде о том, насколько корректно будет себя сувствовать железо под 7 виндой. Могут быть сбои или чего хуже? 10 винда полный отстой с её слишком "умной" системой и обновлениями по 3гб, которые нельзя выключить

Comment: ну формально, можно настроить чтобы ставились только критические обновления. ставьте 8.1 там вроде настраивались еще обновления, если с 7кой проблемы какие то

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нет, фатальных сбоев не будет, но максимальной производительности от своего железа Вы не получите. 
У нас работают два системных блока на базе **Kaby Lake** под управлением **Windows 7**. Всё нормально, но пару драйверов пришлось ставить от **Windows 8.1**